# Creation of nondeterministic finite-state machine for a word which doesn't contain a certain symbol

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language

The given alphabet is

$$\Sigma = \left\{ a, b, c \right\}$$

I am looking for a nondeterministic finite-state machine which accepts the following words:

$$L=\left\{w\in \Sigma^* \mid \exists x\in\Sigma:\left| w \right|_x=0\right\}$$

with $$\left|Q \right| = 4$$ (number of states).

In simple words the machine should accept all words which use a maximum of 2 symbols out of 3 of the alphabet. This exercise should be rather easy but I just don't know how to count the number of different symbols.

Comment: Can you do one that accepts words that only use $a$ and $b$, which has $2$ states? Then combine multiple copies of that.

Comment: Finite automata can't count, since they are finite and the set of possible counts is not. Fortunately, this exercise doesn't require you to count; it only asks if the count is 0. Checking whether something exists by counting those things and then comparing the count to 0 is a conceptual bug frequently found in software but rare in real life. If someone asked you whether there were any redheads in your city, would you do an exhaustive census of the entire population to get a precise count? Or would you just look around until you saw one?

Comment: @StefanAlbrecht: In my opinion this machine would have a state $$q_0$$ with a loop for $$a$$ and an epsilon transition to state $$q_1$$ which has a loop for $$b$$. Both states are final states.

Comment: @stackNutzer89 Your automaton $q_0 \xrightarrow{a} q_0 \xrightarrow{\varepsilon} q_1 \xrightarrow{b} q_1$ does not accept $ba$...